# How to design a function with an optional random seed argument to be passed to mt19937

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

In R I can build the following `roll_die(seed = NULL)` function that returns a random integer between 1 and 6, and it allows **the option** of specifying a seed for the RNG.

```
roll_die_r <- function(seed = NULL){
  # Returns a random number between 1 and 6
  # Optionally specify a RNG seed

  set.seed(seed)
  return(sample(x = 1:6, size = 1L))
}
```

This is nice because I can call it with the default `seed = NULL` and get back a random value *or* I can call it with a specified seed value so that I can get reproducible results.

```
roll_die_r()  # random
roll_die_r(seed = 0)  # always returns 6
```

How do I implement the same thing in c++ using [mt19937](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/)? The best I can come up with is

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <random>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int roll_die_cpp(int seed = -1){
  // Returns a random integer between 1 and 6
  // Optionally specify a RNG seed

  std::mt19937 mt;

  // Seed the RNG
  if(seed == -1) seed = std::random_device{}();
  mt.seed(seed);

  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);
  int result = dist(mt);
  return result;
}
```

But this is not ideal because the user might accidentally `call roll_die_cpp(seed = -1)` and expect to get back a reproducible result which is not the case.

```
roll_die_cpp()  # random
roll_die_cpp(seed = 0)  # always returns 5
roll_die_cpp(seed = -1)  # random
```

My question is not specifically about the `roll_die()` method or random number generators - it's more about the function design. In R I often use functions with default parameters set to NULL but I don't know how to accomplish the same thing in c++.

UPDATE:
Here's another example of what I'm getting at.

R function

```
return_0 <- function(msg = NULL){
  if(!is.null(msg)) print(msg)
  return(0L)
}
return_0()  # doesn't print a message
return_0("hello world")  # prints hello world
```

cpp function

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int return_0_cpp(std::string msg = "don't print"){
  if(msg != "don't print") Rcpp::Rcout << msg;
  return(0);
}

return_0_cpp()  # doesn't print a message
return_0_cpp(msg = "hello world")  # prints hello world
return_0_cpp(msg = "don't print")  # doesn't print a message
```

Notice how awkward `return_0_cpp()` is. What's a clean way of doing in cpp what I've created in R?

Comment: How about `int roll_die_cpp(int seed = std::random_device{}())`?

Comment: I doubt you actually want to seed your generator each time. You should just have a single instance of `std::mt19937` that you keep around and seed once.

Comment: Seeding a `std::mt19937` correctly is not so easy. It has a huge number of potential states, way more than can be represented by a single `int`. For example, see [this post on Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's a good solution to this specific example, I think you're missing the broader point of my question. Let me update my question real quick..

Comment: If you want a general solution for optional arguments, you may want to look at [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Otherwise, you can always provide overloads with fewer arguments which then call the more elaborate overload by providing the default value for the missing arguments. Edit : if you want to explicitly handle someone giving a `nullptr` argument to signal that a default value is needed, you can overload with a [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) argument.

Comment: We have a (templated) `Nullable` for Rcpp to allow values to be null.  (And for the C++ listener: R does everything with union-style type `SEXP` so we can't just pass a `nullptr`).

Comment: Thanks Ralf and Dirk. Sorry I did not find the linked SO question when I was searching for this.  Although, user463035818's solution below seems like a nice one as well.

Comment: While you have answers from very capable C++ experts, I have to ask if the ultimate purpose of this is R package development. If so, you should know that "compiled code should not call the system random number generators... nor should the C++11 random number library be used, nor any other third-party random number generators..." ([Section 1.6 of the Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-portable-packages))

Comment: @duckmayr my ultimate goal is to build cross platform tools like [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) and [lightgbm](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM), but I'm in the early stages of learning c++.  (Note that both packages use `mt19937`, as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In R I often  use functions with default parameters set to NULL but I don't know how
>   to accomplish the same thing in c++.

[`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (since C++17) is made for optional values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

void fun(std::optional<int> v = std::nullopt) {
    if (v) {
        std::cout << "value passed = " << v.value();
    } else {
        std::cout << "no value passed";
    }
}

int main(){ 
    fun();
    fun(4);
}
```

As a sidenote: I would be careful with making the same function do two different things depending on the number of parameters passed. One could argue that

```
dice.seed(0); 
auto x = dice.roll();
```

is more explicit and readable than

```
auto x = dice.roll(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use a header only library that works something like this (much much simplified):

```
namespace ran {

inline std::mt19937& generator()
{
    thread_local static std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    return mt;
}

template<typename Integral>
void seed(Integral n)
{
    generator().seed(std::mt19937::result_type(n));
}

template<typename Integral>
Integral number(Integral min, Integral max)
{
    using dist_type = typename std::uniform_int_distribution<Integral>;
    thread_local static dist_type dist;

    return dist(generator(), typename dist_type::param_type(min, max));
}

} // namespace ran
```

Using `thread_local static` ensures thread safety while keeping performance. It reuses the same random number generator seeding it just once at the beginning or you can re-seed it at any time with a specific value.

```
int main()
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << ran::number(3, 9) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    ran::seed(5);

    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << ran::number(3, 9) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```