# srand() is not working when used with non-constant parameter

Tags: c++, random, srand, c++-experimental

I've got a problem with `srand()`. It only works when I use a number as a parameter, for example `srand(1234)`, but when I try to use it with 'n' or with time (as below), then `randint()` keeps returning the same value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int random = experimental::randint(0, 9);
        cout << random;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think `srand` and `experimental::randint` are connected in any way.

Comment: [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3d6cfd741b60fbb). I second that as well, part of the point of `randint` is that you don't have to deal with `srand`.

Comment: @MarkRansom so why it is working well when I fill number before run.

Comment: @chris I keep getting 1654 as result without srand

Comment: int n;
cin >> n;
srand(n);  this does nothing also, but srand(5) works well

Comment: It is experimental. Check your implementation's support of `randint`. You can probably see the source code of it directly.

Comment: Did you try `reseed()`?

Comment: @Galik LOL i tried it yesterday but probably made a mistake somewhere, i tried it once again today and its atleast working but not very well.  Clearly there is a pattern and similar n returns similar results. reseed(1) returns 0174, (2) 0255, (3) 0323, and it just keep increasing like that. same with reseed(time(nullptr)).

Comment: @RETOVSKEJ `std::experimental::randint` uses `std::default_random_engine` which gives no guarantees of quality. I recommend using a specific random gnerator like the Mersenne Twister. A bit like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915020/efficient-random-number-generation-with-c11-random/35915320#35915320

Comment: This is better if you want to set specific seeds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881672/how-to-design-a-function-with-an-optional-random-seed-argument-to-be-passed-to-m/52881921#52881921

Answer (score 1):

The C function [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) is meant to be used in combination with the C function [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand). These are separate functions from those in C++'s `std::experimental` header. The [`randint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/randint) function from the latter is meant to be used with the [`reseed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reseed) function from the same header:

```
#include <experimental/random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::experimental::reseed();

    for (int i = 4; i--; ) {
        int random = std::experimental::randint(0, 9);
        std::cout << random << '\n';
    }
}
```

However, there is no need to use experimental features here. Since C++11, there is [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
 
int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(0, 9); // Default type is 'int'
 
    for (int i = 4; i--; ) {
        int random = distrib(gen);
        std::cout  << random << '\n';
    }
}
```

This method is more flexible than the one from the C standard library and should, generally, be preferred in C++.